# how to call static block in custom module template phtml file?

Tags: magento2

I want to call **magento** 2 admin static block in my custom module template phtml file. Anybody have idea? how can i do this task ?
below code working in theme phtml file but not working in my custom module phtml file.

```
 <?php echo $block->getLayout()->
       createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->
       setBlockId('login_register_text_2')->toHtml();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code snippet if you want to show CMS Static Block in any template in Magento 2

```
echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
          ->setBlockId('your_block_identifier')
          ->toHtml();
```